# Jquery multiple animations multiple elements one onclick function

Tags: jquery, animation, element

Okay so I have a table with 3 images all in the class .iconeffect each with a different ids(#effect1,2,3) and I am trying to animate them onclick. This is the current code I have but there is a problem with the 2nd animations.

```
$('#effect1').click(function() {
    $(this).finish();
    $(this).animate({ right: 200 });
    $('#effect2, #effect3').animate({ left: 1000 });
});
```

Now this code, should animate #effect1 one way and the other two effects the opposite way(offscreen), the first one animates but the second and third effects dont animate. They move to their end position after hovering over them. If you hover over them prior to clicking the first one they will animate normally.

EDIT: JSFIDDLE http://jsfiddle.net/9EqNy/24/

Comment: Can you show us a failing example in jsfiddle?

Comment: Can you add a sample CSS for this 3 DIVs please ?

Comment: Post your html and css, the problem could be in css.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9EqNy/24/ there you go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Juste add position:relative in the CSS for your 3 DIVs:

```
#effect1 {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:red;
    position:relative;
}
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/wchXQ/

Answer (score 0):

you need to disable the queue for the animations that shall run at the same time:

```
$('#effect1').click(function() {
    $(this).finish();
    $(this).animate({ right: 200, queue : false });
    $('#effect2, #effect3').animate({ left: 1000, queue : false });
});
```

From the jQuery API Docs:

> ### queue (`default: true`)
>
> Type: Boolean or String A Boolean indicating whether to place the
>   animation in the effects queue. If false, the animation will begin
>   immediately.

[Edit]
try this:

```
$('#effect1').click(function() {
    $(this).finish();
    var self = this;
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(self).animate({ right: 200, queue : false })
    },1);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#effect2, #effect3').animate({ left: 1000, queue : false });
    },1);
});
```

Comment: I just tried the second code you pasted, and the first effect doesnt animate at all and the 2nd and 3rd dont animate but disappear on hover after clicking the first.

Comment: weird ... are you shure your animations don't interfere with css? (like relative positioning vs absolute positioning)

Comment: ok wait...there's a error, i edited again...."this" would not be referenced in the function...